# How to define/attach acronym to figure without showing it in the text?

Tags: floats, acronyms

I use the [`acronym`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/acronym) package to manage my acronyms.
Is it possible to attach an acronym definition to the LaTeX code of an included figure (PDF, not LaTeX figure)?

That is, I want to make sure my LaTeX code generates a warning when it doesn't find the acronym in the acronym definition list. However, it should not be displayed (i.e., I don't want to define/display it in the caption)

For example something like:

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{fig_10.pdf}
    \begin{usedacronymsbutnotshown}
        \acs{MWE}
    \end{usedacronymsbutnotshown}
\caption{Blablabla}
\label{fig:pnet:10}
\end{figure}

Overview of all acronyms in my document:

\begin{acronym}
\acro{HDTV}{High-definition Television}
\acro{MWE}{Minimum Working Example}   %If line not here, I would get a compile warning
...
\end{acronym}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `acronym` each acronym `<id>` has an associated macro `\fn@<id>`. The following code defines `\useac{<id>}` which tests if the acronym exists by testing the associated command and if it exists calls `\acronymused{<id>}` which tells `acronym` that the acronym has been used.

This way you get a warning if the acronym is not defined in the list of acronyms *and* the acronym used with `\useac{<id>}` will be marked as used and will be printed in the list of acronyms also when you use the `printonlyused` option. The test if the acronym is defined is for avoiding an `missing \item` error if the acronym is not present in the `{acronym}` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}

\newcommand*\useac[1]{%
   \expandafter\ifx\csname fn@#1\endcsname\relax
     \PackageWarning{acronym}{Acronym `#1' is not defined}%
   \else
    \acronymused{#1}%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{fig_10.pdf}
  \useac{MWE}
  \caption{Blablabla}
  \label{fig:pnet:10}
\end{figure}

Overview of all acronyms in my document:

\begin{acronym}
  \acro{HDTV}{High-definition Television}
  \acro{MWE}{Minimum Working Example}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could one of the phantom commands to insert an empty box.

```
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \Huge FIGURE%
  \rlap{\hphantom{\ac*{MWE}}}
  \caption{Blablabla}
  \label{fig:pnet:10}
\end{figure}

Overview of all acronyms in my document:

\begin{acronym}
  \acro{HDTV}{High-definition Television}
  %% warning because this is commented \acro{MWE}{Minimum Working Example}
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

Here the `\rlap` is to don't let the empty space influence anything.

This is a kludge, but there is no ready command in `acronym` for just referencing like this. There is a command `\acused` that doesn't print anything, but it only marks the acronym as used as regarding short/long form, and doesn't generate a warning.

Comment: Hmm. When I compile this, the `\phantom{\ac{MWE}` block is not shown (as intended) but it *does* influence the indenting of the figure (`\Huge FIGURE` text in your example)

Comment: `\phantom` takes up space. You could enclose it in a `\rlap` (and avoid leaving whitespace before and after), but the approach is a hack anyway.

Comment: @alexis, Right, I've updated it like that.